# How can I replace "11" in line no.7 with this Function "(WEEKNUM(TODAY(),21))", So that I can get Week no automatically

Tags: excel, vba, date, numbers

```
Sub Check()
Dim shp As Shape
Dim r As Range, cel As Range
```

" Set shp = ActiveSheet.Shapes("Shape1") 'Shape name to change
Set r = Range("F6:AW6")

```
For Each cel In r

    If cel.Value = "11" Then `this line
        shp.Left = cel.Left - (shp.Width / 2) + (cel.Width / 2)
        shp.Top = cel.Top - (shp.Height / 2) + (cel.Height / 2)

    Exit For
    End If
Next cel


End Sub  "
```

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing line 7 with the following;

`If cel.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.WeekNum(Now,21) Then`

Comment: It's working. thanks.also I want to know, how can I make this micro will run automatically. without manually clicking on run or any button everytime.

Comment: You can add an event to the worksheet object in the VBA editor so that when a named range changes your subroutine will be triggered.  Try this code snipit;

`Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)`

`If Not Intersect(Me.Range("rMyNamedRange"), Target) Is Nothing Then`

`    Call MySub`

`End If`

`End Sub`

Comment: thanks again for your speedy reply, say if I want to make "11" depend on any cell value. how can I do that?? say value in Cell A2.